# How to Apache2 select other proxy on first proxy fail?

Tags: apache-2.2

Ubuntu Apache2,

I have configured apache2 with reverse proxy,

But if first proxy server(IP-A) is not running then 
I want to pass request to other proxy server(IP-B)

How can I able to do this ?

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 0):

You'll create a balancer group, with one member set as a hot spare.

Say 192.0.2.5 is your primary server, and 192.0.2.6 is your secondary, which should only get requests if the primary is down..

```
<Proxy balancer://proxygroup>
  BalancerMember http://192.0.2.5
  BalancerMember http://192.0.2.6 status=+H
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://proxygroup/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://proxygroup/
```